# yum update minor versions only

Tags: yum, update, rhel7

On my server I am running Gitlab community edition for my development repositories and today I found a error that was caused by my `yum update` cronjob.

What happened is that an update from 7.x to 8.x was installed which requires a lot of extra actions to install successfully.

Therefore a zip download of the repository wasn't available (a json file was returned with no files)

The question I wanna ask: Has the yum package an option to only update minor versions (e.g 7.1 to 7.2 but no 7.1 to 8.0)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get that from a third party repository?

Comment: This is a repository problem. Normally, you have repo "X for RHEL6" and "X for RHEL7" and it's up to the maintainer to assure that whatever they put there, doesn't require much attention during `yum update`. Until you migrate from RHEL6 to RHEL7 of course :)

Comment: @Michael gitlab provides since 7.10 yum and apt-get repositories.

Comment: Not very well, it seems...

Comment: @Kubanczyk it is not a problem from the os version it is a problem of the package version. For major updates you should expect problems without testing. And I want yum to not install new major versions and only new minor updates.

Comment: Yes, I get you. This is a repository problem. If RHEL7 started with gitlab 7, to this day it should stay with it. You use RHEL for stability and for effortless `yum update`, so it's considered best practice. There should be a separate repository for incoming RHEL8 which could contain gitlab 8.x or gitlab 11.x, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Yum doesn't provide a way to follow a specific semantic version, but there is a way to lock a particular package version in place, using the yum `versionlock` plugin.

```
yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
```

This will allow locking a package to the *currently installed* version.

For example:

```
yum versionlock add gitlab*
```

To update the package, you will have to remove the lock first.

```
yum versionlock delete gitlab*
```

Comment: Can I lock on e.g. 8.* with this plugin?

Comment: @JeroenDeMeerleer I spent the very first line of this post answering that!

Comment: I prefer --exclude in my cronjob in that case as this requires less pain when updating the excluded packages 

Comment: @JeroenDeMeerleer Be very careful with `--exclude`. It's a blunt instrument and can exclude far more than you think.

Comment: Is there any reference that you can share to back up this claim - ```Yum doesn't provide a way to follow a specific semantic version```