# Can 'yum update --security' upgrade the major version or only the patch version?

Tags: yum

I could not find a definite answer on it online. I only want to apply any patches available, but not upgrade the major version of the package that I want to apply security updates to.

This question - [yum update minor versions only](https://serverfault.com/questions/737934/yum-update-minor-versions-only) - does have an answer that says that `Yum doesn't provide a way to follow a specific semantic version`, however it doesn't provide any reference to back it up. I have posted a comment there seeking a reference, but since the Q&A is from 2015, I don't have much hope of getting a response there.

Comment: Is it work for you?
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/98873

Answer (score 1):

The release model underpinning RHEL is that the distro uses a frozen set of upstream releases.

When updates are required, they are backported from a later release to the distribution release by the RPM packager. Take, for instance, PHP. RHEL 7 (and hence Centos 7 and other distros compliant with RHEL 7) comes with PHP 5.4.16 There have been multiple updates released by the distributors - a quick Google and I found "php-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64.rpm" - this is the 48th RHEL version of the package. The major version number has not changed. The minor version number has not changed.

There are other upstream releases of PHP available as Centos/RHEL rpms outside of the official respositories; remirepo.net is a popular one. There I can find (for RHEL7/Centos 7) PHP 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7.1, 7.2....8.3 currently. But in order to switch to one of these, I would need to install them alongside or after removing the standard version - yum will not transition the upstream vendor release.